# Is there a device which allows switching between two networks remotely?

Tags: networking, network-share

I'm looking for a way to remotely swap between two different networks. We have two separate networks in our main building that we use for different things and they need to be kept separate.

The issue is that my office is across the parking lot in a small building.  We have one fiber line ran from our main building to network us in.

I know there are boxes where you can switch between two different network cables by pressing a button but is there one where swapping can be done remotely over the network?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, what you need to do is switch the vlan that your network is connected to. You'd need a small managed ethernet switch at the far end, with your fiber connected into one port, and the other two networks into two of the other ports on the switch.

Assign a different "untagged" (sometimes called "default") VLAN ID to each separate network (say, VLAN 100 and VLAN200). Then for your fiber port, just change the "untagged" VLAN network to either 100 or 200 (or whatever VLAN IDs you chose) to bridge your fiber onto the different networks.

It's not going to be a physical button, but if you buy appropriate hardware it could easily be a script that you run.

Comment: IMHO, IP sub-net based routing is almost always a better idea than VLANs.

Comment: @symcbean the OP says they need to keep the networks separate, and I feel that adding routes does not keep them separate any more. Also, we don't know if they have any overlapping IP space, and even if they go down that route, they will still have to buy a managed switch that can do the vlans, but you would just 802.1q trunking for the link to their office, so they can always do that _later_ if they needed.